# SunOS. Find files that do not contain the substring 'foo' in the file name

Tags: find, filenames

Now I exclude files by their extension.

```
  find ./export/home/ ! \( -name *.log -o -name *.out -o -name *.tmp \)
```

But I also want to exclude files with the name containing some string 'foo'. 
Need some sort of analog " *like '%foo%'* " (PL\SQL), to exclude files such as "1_foo2".

I can not use the GNU version of the command "find".

Answer (score 1):

You are pretty close:

```
find ./export/home/ -type f ! \( -name "*.log" -o -name "*.out" -o 
                                 -name "*.tmp" -o -name "*foo*"  \)
```